# Display nested JSON on table with angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular

i'm trying to populate a table with a nested json, the json looks like this :

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nombre": "Dave",
        "apellido": "Atkins",
        "curso": "Maths",
        "estudiante": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "nombre": "Student1",
                "apellido": "Test1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "nombre": "Student2",
                "apellido": "Test2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Basically, i need to the table with the students, but i can't make it work. I keep getting [object,object][object,object] on the table. this data comes from a backend endpoint like this:

```
profesores: Profesor[];

listarProfesores(): void {
    this.profesorService.getAll()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.profesores = data;
          console.log(data);
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
```

And this is the html i'm using, i still cant figure out where/how to access that data:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3 style="text-align: center;">Listado de Estudiantes</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead style="text-align: center;">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Apellidos</th>
                        <th>Editar</th>
                        <th>Eliminar</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody style="text-align: center;">
                    <tr *ngFor="let profesor of profesores" class="text-center">
                        <td>{{profesor.nombre}}</td>
                        <td>{{profesor.apellido}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-warning">Editar</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button (click)="eliminarEstudiante(profesor.estudiante.id)"
                                class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it using 2 ngFor like this:

```
<tbody *ngFor="let profesor of profesores" style="text-align: center;">
                    <tr *ngFor="let student of profesor.estudiante" class="text-center">
                        <td>{{student.nombre}}</td>
                        <td>{{student.apellido}}</td>
                        <td>{{profesor.curso}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-warning">Editar</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button (click)="eliminarEstudiante(profesor.estudiante.id)"
                                class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```